# How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4

Tags: angular

In Http Module I can easily get the response code using response.status, but when I used HttpClient Module I cannot get the response.status, it shows undefined.

So, how can I get the response.status using HttpClient module in Angular 4. Please help.

Comment: This is all explained here: https://angular.io/guide/http

Comment: I checked the documentation but I didn't find the exact solution to find the status code from response.

Comment: Look at the section "Reading the full response".

Comment: Thanks for your help... It works now.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[From this section](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response), this is the adjusted code

```
http
  .post<T>('/yoururl', whateverYourPostRequestIs, {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
     console.log(resp);
  });
```

the answer is {observe: 'response'}. you can then view the logged resp and pick/choose what you want.

Comment: As the method is post, `{observe: 'response'}` would be sent as a request body. So that should be on the third parameter.

Comment: It's still not clear hot to get the status! I'm only getting the body.

Comment: But I need the second argument to send custom headers for authentications. How can still add {observe: 'response'}?

Comment: @LeeMoe Thats no problem! Since the thrid parameter of the post request is taking in an object, you can pass in both. For details see my answer below! :)

Comment: @LeeMoe, you’ll want to look into interceptors for things like authentication. There are both request and response interceptors that you can set up to manage things like error codes, authentication etc...

Comment: can someone please answer my query also. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54827379/angular-5-subscribe-read-httpstatuscode-204