# How to read the status from response in angular http?

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpresponse, angular-httpclient

I am facing some problem in reading the status code from response.

I am calling api in service,

```
return this.http.get<string>( this.remoteServer + '/google.com/open', httpOptions);
```

In my controller I have,

```
open() {
    this.openService.open(this.selected.qrCode)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
       console.log(data);
       this.toastService.showSuccess('Unlock Successfull', 'success');
      }
    );
  }
```

Now I want to read the http statustext,

the sample http response I am getting from the above call is.

> HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText:
>   "OK", url:
>   "https://google.com/open", ok:
>   false, …}

How to read the status text in the controller.

Please help me

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify `{ observe: 'response' }` as the second parameter to `get` request which gives you the full response data.

If you want to send other options like `headers` or `params` along with it, just rollup all of them in a single object this way.

```
const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}), params : myParams, observe: 'response'}
```

[Reference](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response)

```
return this.http.get<string>(
    this.remoteServer + '/google.com/open', httpOptions).subscribe((data) => {
        console.log(data.status);     // staus 200
        console.log(data.statusText);  // OK
});
```

Comment: What is Config?

Comment: Well that's a expected response type. I simply used the code from angular.io. You can use it as string in your case.

Comment: one more small doubt, If I want to pass even http options as third argument in get(), it shows it expected only 1 - 2 parameters but got 3. Can you please explain? Thanks for the repsonse

Comment: You should be sending it as the second parameter only instead with another property `{ observe: 'response', header : httpHeader}`. I assume you want to send header. If you want to send other options just add parameters to that second argument object.

Comment: yeah, i want to send even httpOptions which i have set.

Comment: Just roll up all your options as single object and add key-> value `observe: 'response'` to the same object and pass this object as a second parameter.

Comment: const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'observe': 'response',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'}), is this correct? Please correct me If I am wrong

Comment: No, do not mix it with header It should be this way `const httpOptions = { headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}),  'observe': 'response'}`

Answer (score 2):

We can also get the complete response by adding the { observe: 'response' } in our request.

```
return this._http.get<any>(this.serverUrl+'categories/'+id, { observe: 'response' })
```

Answer (score 1):

The {observe:'response'} options qualifier can be added to either a get or a put on the HttpClient object. It should be added as an additional comma separated field to any existing options which you might have defined. See below for an example of a simple Put statement modified to return the full http content. This can be used for standardized status reporting in your application.

```
    body = this.currentDocument;

    let url = environment.base_url + 'api/Document/updateDocument';

    // For a put the options block is the third parameter. For a get this would be the second
    this.httpClient.put(url, body,
        {
            headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }),
            withCredentials: true,
            // Add the observe block to the existing option parameters
            observe:'response'
        })
        .subscribe(
            response => {

                statusMessage = new StatusMessage();
                statusMessage.HttpStatus = response.status;
                statusMessage.StatusText = response.statusText;

                // This example uses an EventEmitter but you could do any kind of logging here
                this.updateStatusPanel.emit(statusMessage);
                // The JSON body of this response can be accessed via the response.body parameter
            },
            err => {}
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

Will `data.status` give you what you want?