# Angular 7- Need to intercept 200 status code from API before the data arrives, show an alert and then subscribe/process the data later

Tags: angular, angular7, response, http-status-codes

So, I'm new to Angular in general.

The scenario goes like there is an API return a blob data that takes ~5-10 seconds for the response data to be downloaded.

**I need a way to intercept so soon as the API gives 200 status before the response data arrives**, so I can show an alert/toaster saying 'the data will be available soon' (or something like that). Also, on getting the data, need a way to subscribe/process it.
Is there a way to achieve this (built-in or any) ?

Sample code-

```
this.materialService
  .getMaterialReport(requestBody, this.selectedLocation)
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroyAllSubscriptions))
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      if (data.body) {
        saveAs(data.body, 'material-report' + new Date().getTime() + '.zip');
        this.showSuccessAlert = true;
        this.showErrorAlert = false;
      } else {
        this.showErrorAlert = true;
        this.showSuccessAlert = false;
        this.fileDownloadError = 'No records found for this filter';
      }
      this.showReportLoader = false;
    },
    error => {
      this.showErrorAlert = true;
      this.showSuccessAlert = false;
      this.fileDownloadError = (error.indexOf('500') === -1 ) ? 'No records found for this filter' : 'Error while fetching records';
      this.showReportLoader = false;
    }
  );
```

Comment: I think you want to do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51049806/how-to-read-the-status-from-response-in-angular-http/51049956#51049956

Comment: @Xissor nope, not quite.