# how to read http status code error in component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services

I know this has been asked before but I can't seem to find the answer, how to read status code from http..?

```js
this.bookingService.save(this.param)
    .subscribe(
        data =>
            swal({
                "title": "Succes!",
                "text": "Your data saved",
                "type": "success",
                "confirmButtonClass": "btn btn-secondary m-btn m-btn--wide"
            }),
        error => console.log('error'),
            () => this.router.navigate('Succes')
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the status code from the error,

```
this.bookingService.save(this.param).subscribe(
data =>{
  console.log(data);
},
(err) => {console.log(err)});
```

To get the error msg back, add a catch that will return the error object:

```
 save(book){
      return this.http.post('http:..../',book)
        .map(res => res)
        .catch(this.handleError);
 }

  private handleError(error: any) { 
      let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message : error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
      return Observable.throw(error);
  }
```

Comment: just access res.status

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4