# Angular 5 Subscribe read HttpStatusCode 204

Tags: angular, angular5

I am using Angular 5 in the project and making API calls to fetch the data.

Example code:-

```
this.userSvc.addPhone(this.userID, this.countryCode, this.phoneNumber)
   .subscribe(data => {
       console.log('Phone Added Successfully')
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { console.log(err.message) });
```

**userSvc Function** :-

```
    addPhone(userId, countryCode, phoneNumber) {
    return this.HttpClient.Post(this.rootUrl + "add-phonetouser?id=" + userId + "&countrycode=" + countryCode + "&phonenumber=" + phoneNumber
        , { headers: this.header });
}
```

From the web-api method, i am trying to pass the NoContent HttpCode and would like to read the status code on the angular side.

Now i would like to understand how do i read this NoContent HttpStatusCode from the angular side.

web-API code looks like this :-

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByName(username);
if (user == null) {
   return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NoContent, "User not found.");
} else {}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4 this might be helpful for you

Comment: Your api response is conveying the wrong message. I would recommend a 404 Not Found instead of a 204. Then circle back to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4

Answer (score 3):

from Angular Docs:

> The response body doesn't return all the data you may need. Sometimes
>   servers return special headers or status codes to indicate certain
>   conditions that are important to the application workflow.
>
> Tell HttpClient that you want the full response with the observe
>   option:

You need to use { observe: 'response' } in your API call from Angular.

```
 addPhone(userId, countryCode, phoneNumber): Observable<HttpResponse<any>> {
        return this.HttpClient.Post(this.rootUrl + "add-phonetouser?id=" + userId +
         "&countrycode=" + countryCode + "&phonenumber=" + phoneNumber
            , {}, { headers: this.header,  observe: 'response' } );
        }
```

And then consume it like this:

```
this.userSvc.addPhone(this.userID, this.countryCode, this.phoneNumber)
   .subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data.status);
       console.log(data.body);
    },
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { console.log(err.message) });
```

Comment: Can you please share an example with my code sample in context.

Comment: addPhone is present in the question body of this post. Please suggest.

Comment: I see that addPhone method is being called. Can you please post the method body of addPhone which is present in user service?

Comment: Please have a look. I have added the fn code into the question body.

Comment: @Karan: I have updated the answer with your use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188997/discussion-between-ritesh-and-karan).

Comment: @Karan, did the solution solve your problem.. if yest please upvote :)