# Angular 6: How to get response status code

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

How do I get the service code? I try the code below, but it does not log anything.

In a service.ts file.

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

postForgotPass(email): Observable<Response> {

return this.http.post<Response>(envi.apiUrl +'/user/forgotpassword', {
  "email": email,
  "headers": headers,
  observe: 'response'

})
}
```

In my component.ts file

```
sendForgotPass() {
 return this.service.postForgotPass(this.emailFormControl.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res.status);
      })
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `Observable<HttpResponse>`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response):

```
getConfigResponse(): Observable<HttpResponse<Config>> {
  return this.http.get<Config>(
    this.configUrl, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

Usage

```
this.configService.getConfigResponse()
    // resp is of type `HttpResponse<Config>`
    .subscribe(resp => {
      // display its headers
      const keys = resp.headers.keys();
      this.headers = keys.map(key =>
        `${key}: ${resp.headers.get(key)}`);

      // access the body directly, which is typed as `Config`.
      this.config = { ... resp.body };
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

It is because non 2xx status codes are mapped to an error. You need to hook provide a handler for second parameter of subscribe(errors)

```
sendForgotPass() {
    return this.service.postForgotPass(this.emailFormControl.value)
        .subscribe(res => console.log(res.status), err => console.log('error', err.status))
    }
```

Comment: This work, but even 2xx codes are logging as "error:200". Why is that?

Comment: Something else must be wrong. Try logging what is in err variable. Maybe some deserialisation or content type is wrong. Check network tab of browser that you get what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(response === undefined || response === ''  || response === null)
{  
    this.isStatusCode[i] = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";

constructor(
private httpClient: HttpClient){}

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(this.API_URL, {observe: 'response'})
        .subscribe({
          next: (res) => {
console.error(res.status)  // api status in header
console.error(res.body) // response from api
}
})`
```

**{observe: 'response'} in get method gives full response object**