# How do I get the response code in angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I have the following code in an angular 7 app

```
insertAccount(submittedAccount:Account):Observable<Account>{
    return this.http.post<Account>(this.baseApiUrl+"Account",submittedAccount,this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(
      map(response=>{
        return response;
      }
    ))
   }
```

How do I get the http response code? For instance if it returns a 401 error I need to handle it and currently it is obviously simply returning the object.

----Update----

Okay so I followed the solutions below but the map method was never reached as there was no response as such (I assume because it failed due to a 401)

So I changed it to the following

```
let result:Account[]=[];
    this.http.get<HttpResponse<Account[]>>(this.baseApiUrl+"Account",this.httpNormalOptions).pipe(map(
      response=>{
       return response;
      }
    )).subscribe(r=>{result= r.body},p=>{if(p.status===401){this.clearToken()}})

    return result;
```

However is obviously now does not return an observable... Is that an issue? (I am pretty new to observables) Is there a benefit to returning an observable over simply returning the Account[] object?

Just for completeness I am building the headers I send with the response as follows

```
this.httpNormalOptions = {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.auth_token,
          observe:'response'
        })
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Catching errors in Angular HttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46019771/1260204)

Comment: It is not a direct duplicate as I have a further issue that is not answered by the listed questions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to catch exception correctly from http.request()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35326689/1260204)

Answer (score 4):

You need to tell Angular you want to get the [complete response](https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response) with the option `observe: 'response'`, this will give you access to the headers and the status code:

```
this.http.post<Account>(url, { observe: 'response' }).pipe(
    map(response => response.headers['status'])
)
```

The response will be of type `HttpResponse<Account>`.

Comment: I still only have an account object (ie response is of type 'Account')

Comment: @coolblue2000, the response should be of type `HttpResponse<Account>`