# Angular 8 - Print http response body

Tags: angular

I was using Angular 7 and I used to get the body of the response by:

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

constructor(public http: Http...)

this.http.get(myURL).subscribe(
  (data) => {
    const myURL_body = data['_body'];
  })
```

Now... with angular 8: how would be?

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(public httpClient: HttpClient...)

this.httpClient.get?
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

Comment: Have you tried reading https://angular.io/guide/http?

Answer (score 0):

```js
this.httoClient.get(myURL).subscribe(
(data)=>{
const myURL_body = data['_body'];
}
)
```