# Return multiple values from service to component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using httpmodule to load data from backend. when I load data in service, I return it to component but I also want to return status code to component. `Data` model is already defined and can't change it.

### service

```js
getData(offSet, maxResults): Observable<Data> {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"?offset="+offSet+"&maxResults="+maxResults);
}
```

### component

```js
this.dataService.getData(0, this.maxResults).subscribe((data)=>{
      this.data = data;
      this.total = data.totalCount;
      this.pages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.maxResults);
});
```

## I want

I want to get status code from subscribe callback like below

```js
this.dataService.getData(0, this.maxResults).subscribe((data, status_code)=>{
      this.data = data;
      this.total = data.totalCount;
      this.pages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.maxResults);
});
```

Comment: Have you tried `data.status` ?

Comment: `data` is already defined model. which dont have status property.

Comment: Why does the component need access to the status code? That's a detail of the transport layer, the whole point of having the service is to isolate the components from that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

Comment: question is not about getting status_code. it is about sending back to the component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default Angular `HttpClient` returns the body of the request. You should add `observe: 'response'` `HttpOption` to reach headers, statusCode etc.

so, you should change your service.

```
  getData(offSet, maxResults): Observable<{data: Data, statusCode: number}> {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"?offset="+offSet+"&maxResults="+maxResults, {observe: }).pipe(
      map((response: HttpResponse<Data>) => {
        return {
          data: response.body,
          statusCode: response.status
        }
      });
    )
}
```

Now it returns an object which has `data` and `statusCode` property, so you can reach them as the following;

```
  this.dataService.getData(foo,bar).subscribe(response => {
    const { data, statusCode } = response;
    // do something...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

When doing the HTTP request, you can pass the option `observe: 'response'`. Then instead of the data, a `HttpResponse` object is being returned, which also contains the status code:

**Service:**

```js
getData(offSet, maxResults): Observable<HttpResponse<Data>> {
    return this.http.get(this.url+"?offset="+offSet+"&maxResults="+maxResults, { observe: 'response' });
}
```

**Component:**

```js
this.dataService.getData(0, this.maxResults).subscribe((response)=>{
      this.data = response.body;
      this.total = response.body.totalCount;
      this.pages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.maxResults);
      // you can use response.status here
});
```