# how to convert response body based on status code in Angular 8

Tags: angular

The api returns 2 status code depending on file size.
For 200,it returns a json string which I have converted to Object using transformImportCSVResponse().
For 201, it returns a text as response ("File upload is in progress")

Right now it's failing for 201 as it's not able to convert to json

How to process both based on status code.

```js
this.httpClient.post(url, uploadedFile, {params: httpParams}).pipe(
      catchError(err => throwError(err)))
      .pipe(map(this.transformImportCSVResponse))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map(this.transformImportCSVResponse)` is unsafe as the context of `transformImportCSVResponse` function will **not** `this`, but something else.

```
this.httpClient.post(url, uploadedFile, {params: httpParams}).pipe(
  map(res => {
    if (res.status == 201) {
      return { status: 'uploading' };
    }

    return res;
  }),
  catchError(err => throwError(err)),
  map(res => this.transformImportCSVResponse(res)),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that 200 and 201, actually all 2XX responsens are not treated as an error.
So what You can do is:

```
http
  .post<T>('/yoururl', whateverYourPostRequestIs, {observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(resp => {
     console.log(resp);
  });
```

Code taken from: [How can get HttpClient Status Code in Angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46639154/how-can-get-httpclient-status-code-in-angular-4)

And then do `if(resp.status === 200) { do thomething }`

Try this code:

```
this.http.post(url, uploadedFile, {params: new HttpParams(), observe: 'response'})
  .subscribe(
    resp => {
      if (resp.status === 200) {
        this.transformImportCSVResponse(resp.body);
      }
    },
    error => console.log('oops', error)
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Create two different streams depending upon response status using RxJs [Partition](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/partition) operator.

```
import { partition, map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

const [csvResponse$, otherResponse$] = 
    this.httpClient.post(url, uploadedFile, {params: httpParams}).pipe(
        catchError(err => throwError(err)),
        partition(res => res.status === 200)
    );

csvResponse$.pipe(
    map(resp => this.transformImportCSVResponse(resp))
).subscribe(csvTranformedResponse => console.log(csvTranformedResponse));

otherResponse$.subscribe(otherResp => console.log(otherResp));
```

I have not tested this code